# Convert column of Timestamps to datetime.datetime. Works on 1 row, not on column

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I've looked at every answer on this site, including this one: [convert timestamp to datetime.datetime in pandas.Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22554339/convert-timestamp-to-datetime-datetime-in-pandas-series) and nothing is working. It always returns a Timestamp.

I have a dataframe with a `time` column which contains `class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>` values of the format `2022-06-24 15:07:52`.

I'm trying to use pandas' `pd.df.to_sql` function to write my entire dataframe to a MySQL database. I'm running into an error however because the type of the `time` column in the database is `Datetime`, so I need to convert the Timestamps to Datetime format in the dataframe.

I've tried `df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])`, which returns Timestamps.

The only thing that worked is `df['time'][0].to_pydatetime()` when applied to a single row.
However when I try `df['time'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: x.to_pydatetime())`, it doesn't work. The elements are still Timestamps.

I read in another answer somewhere that `to_pydatetime` won't work on a Series or column, so I also tried to extract the column as a list, then apply `to_pydatetime()` to its elements (which works, each element is converted to `datetime.datetime`) and then put that list back into the dataframe. However when I do that, each element is converted again to a Timestamp...

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @BeRT2me, just tried, still returns `<class 'pandas.libs.tslibs.tiestamps.Timestamp'>`. I'm trying to come up with a small example but there's not much more I can say, it's just a dataframe with that timestamp format

Comment: @BeRT2me, for some reason though, `df['time'][0].to_pydatetime()` returns `datetime.datetime', so it works on a single row

Comment: today I tried it turned out like this: data['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(data['time'], 
                                  unit='s')

Comment: @inquirer, thanks unfortunately still returning Timestamp format

Comment: @jeremyradcliff I showed in the answer how it turned out. Show your details.

Comment: @inquirer, if you print out the type of a datetime element in your dataframe, what do you get? `print(type(df['datetime'][0]`

Comment: Note that in general pandas uses the built-in datetime64 type whenever possible (elements of pd.Timestamp class). It won't use the native Python datetime class, unless special conditions apply, like mixed UTC offsets.

Comment: @FObersteiner, yeah it seems I can't get hte conversion to hold in the dataframe no matter what I try, even though I can temporarily print out the correct type is I apply `.to_pydatetime()` to a single row.
Do you know what would be the best way to get my whole dataframe into a MySQL table? That's my predicament right now. I want to use `df.pd.to_sql()` but the type in the MySQL table is Datetime so it won't go through

Comment: @FObersteiner You can get it to stick to the native python datetime class if you explicitly make the column `object` format. You lose all the `.dt` functionality, but it should work for this use case.  See my answer~

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [1451602801, 1451606401, 1451610001, 1451613601, 1451617201]})
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s')
print(df)
```

Output

```
         time            datetime
0  1451602801 2015-12-31 23:00:01
1  1451606401 2016-01-01 00:00:01
2  1451610001 2016-01-01 01:00:01
3  1451613601 2016-01-01 02:00:01
4  1451617201 2016-01-01 03:00:01
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [1451602801, 1451606401, 1451610001, 1451613601, 1451617201]})
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s')

# Wrap the numpy output as a series and force dtype to object:
df['timestamp'] = pd.Series(df.datetime.dt.to_pydatetime(), dtype='O')
print(type(df.datetime[0]))
print(type(df.timestamp[0]))
```

Output:

```
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```